# SQL Pivot function to group rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

Im trying to transpose a table using PIVOT. 
This is my code at the moment:

```
select distinct to_date,[syst1],[syst2],[syst3]
from MyTable
pivot
(
    count(systems)
    for systems
    in ([syst1],[syst2],[syst3])

)
as PivotTable
order by to_date
```

and this is the result I get:
[image]

What I want is to group rows 33&34 together, and 35&36 together, and 37&38 together
so that they look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pivot should be doing what you want . . . unless `to_date` has a time component.  Does this fix the problem?

```
select to_date, [syst1], [syst2], [syst3]
from (select cast(to_date as date) as to_date, systems
      from MyTable
     ) mt
pivot (count(systems)
       for systems in ([syst1], [syst2], [syst3])
      ) as PivotTable
order by to_date;
```

Comment: That fixed it, but not because of the CAST, there is no time component, but because of the sub-query. Not sure why that worked. Thanks

Comment: @user2343837 . . . SQL Server uses all the non-aggregated columns to define each row after the pivot.  The subquery is selecting only the subset that you want.